# c++: Try catch on construction of a class with a const member

Tags: c++, exception, constructor, try-catch, constants

Consider the following class:

```
class MyClass
{
private:
    const unsigned int num;//num identifies the object. needs to be const
    unsigned int checkNum(unsigned int);// verifies that num has a valid value

public:
    MyClass(unsigned int n): num(checkNum(n)) {}
};

unsigned int MyClass:checkNum(unsigned int n)
{
    if (some_condition)
        throw std::invalid_argument("Invalid number");
    return n;
}
```

The difficulty is that the object must be constructed inside a `try` block because of the range check:

```
int main()
{
    try {
        MyClass mc(1000);
    }
    catch (std::invalid_argument &ia)
    {
        std::cout << ia.what();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that `mc` is then not available outside of the `try` block.

Possible solutions:

1. Extend the `try` block over the whole scope where `mc` is used. Not practical in many cases.
2. Don't throw the exception in the constructor, but throwing it afterwards would be too late.

The only acceptable solution I can think of is to use smart pointers to bring the declaration outside of the `try` block:

```
int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<MyClass> my_class_ptr;
    try {
        my_class_ptr = std::make_unique<MyClass>(1000);
    }
    catch (std::invalid_argument &ia)
    {
        std::cout << ia.what();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Are there any other/better solutions?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you meant for `checkNum` and `checkPin` to be the same name. Please do post **real code** in SO questions. At least one answer seems to have been misled by this.

Answer (score 8):

What do you intend to do with `mc` when its construction was deemed invalid, and "cancelled" via exception?

Having the `try` extend around the entire scope of the object makes perfect sense.

**`mc` *shouldn't* be accessible outside of the `try` block.**

Answer (score 2):

In your point 1, "not practical in many cases" is simply false.

A `try` block is the solution where you want to handle failure.

An alternative is to not handle it.

---

In other news, in your point 2, "Don't make MyClass::num const. Not good , it supposed to be non-mutable for the duration of the object." is very questionable. It is to some extent subject to personal opinion, but technically there's no problem. Also, there's no connection between the `const` and the range checking: that hypothesized connection simply does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

You should validate the ID number *before* constructing the `mc` object with it.  Don't do the validation inside the constructor itself:

```
class MyClass
{
private:
    const unsigned int num;

public:
    MyClass(unsigned int n): num(n) {}
};

unsigned int checkNum(unsigned int n)
{
    if (some_condition)
        throw std::invalid_argument("Invalid number");
    return n;
}

int main()
{
    unsigned int num;
    try {
        num = checkNum(some_input);
    }
    catch (std::invalid_argument &ia)
    {
        std::cout << ia.what();
        return -1;
    }
    MyClass mc(num);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function-try-block to prevent any wished of using mc outside of the try block. : >

```
int main() try{

  return 0;
} catch(...) {

}
```